# Unable to use outside dependencies within custom gradle plugin implementation

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

When attempting to use outside dependencies within a custom gradle plugin I'm building, I am not able to import or use them in any regard.

I've attempted to specify in both the build script and the normal dependencies closure my dependencies. I'm using Gradle 5.5 (wrapper script) and I am using the buildSrc method of writing a custom gradle plugin.

```
// Necessary if loading custom plugins
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

group 'com.foo'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greeterPlugin {
            id = 'com.foo.dbcreation-plugin'
            implementationClass = 'com.foo.dbcreation.DbCreation'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues I see here.

1. `buildscript` does not control the dependencies for your plugin implementation.
2. Use the `plugins {}` DSL block to apply plugins. It is the preferred way: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block
3. Should be using `implementation` over `compile` since `compile` is deprecated as noted in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations

With that said, your Gradle file should be like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'com.foo'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greeterPlugin {
            id = 'com.foo.dbcreation-plugin'
            implementationClass = 'com.foo.dbcreation.DbCreation'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my issue was. For projects being built using the buildSrc directory, you need to have the build.gradle file reside in that directory instead of the root project directory (where the build.gradle normally lives). I just converted the project to a normal gradle project and it works just fine.